# How to disable VS's just-in-time debugging completely?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-xp, fortran

*Why I want to do this?*

First, I never use it - spare me, *this is going to sound ignorant*, but I'm not interested. My debugging comes down to *print* and *if* statements. I've been doing it that way for a while, and have no interest in changing the way that works.

Second, a lot of programs which work until Visual Studio installation suddenly stop working upon it, just as Just-In-Time debugging starts to kick in.

Third, it's crashing some of my old programs (not my own, but programs I use) wherever a second screen is attached. Have no idea why this is happening.

***Is there a way to turn it off completely?***

I've disabled it in Visual Studio's options, but it still comes up with an error

*An unhandled win32 exception ... Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time can be enabled from ...*

*Check the documentation index for ...*

(so in general, it's telling me that it isn't turned on)

***How to disable it completely without uninstalling Visual Studio?***

Comment: Change the AeDebug registry key.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21980503/314373

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to select Debug > "Start without debugging (Ctrl+F5)" from the menu, instead of "Debug > Start (F5)".

You might also want to build your code in release mode when doing this - as the debug builds won't be of any benefit to you if you're not intending to debug them.

Comment: I don't have a problem with debugging "from within VS", but when running programs without even running VS. Programs then tend to crash, and just-in-time kicks in. I need VS for my own programs, but I don't want other programs to crash because of it. On the same machine (have two identical for testing purposes), where VS isn't installed, everything runs fine ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue of a windows program launching the debugger is not really one of changes in Visual Studio but is affected by changes in Windows which controls the JIT. You can build all code in release mode, but often want is just no debug pop ups. This is described in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.80).aspx.

You need to issue the commands:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /f /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /f /v "DontShowUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
```

At that point you can run your programs without invoking the debugger. I do this in a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where reg 2^>nul') do @set theValue=%%a 
if NOT "%theValue%."=="." GOTO :HaveReg
:: Might not have where - check again
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg /? 2^>nul') do @set theValue=%%a 
if NOT "%theValue%."=="." GOTO :HaveReg
echo Unable to change registry keys to turn off program pop-ups
GOTO :DoneRegCheck
:HaveReg
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /f /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /f /v "DontShowUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
:DoneRegCheck
```